# How to update Socket.io handlers without re-connecting in React

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I have a **react native** project that uses **socket.io** to communicate with an express server.

I'm looking for a way to initialize the connection only once, and not to re-connect with every render.

I first tried to wrap the connection inside a `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io(Configs.serverURL);
        ...
        socket.on('connect', () => { ... }
        socket.on('data', () => { ... }
});
```

The problem with that is that I have no access to the socket object outside of this scope and that the handlers won't be updated if any of the values they depend on change.

I then tried to separate the initialization from the handlers by setting some state variable

```
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
...
useEffect(() => {
        setSocket(io(Configs.serverURL));
});

useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('connect, () => { ... });
        ...
}, [dependency1, dependency2])
```

However, I was hit by the error that says `Cannot read property 'on' of null`.

To summarize: I need to initialize the socket instance outside of any local scope, I also need that to happen only once and before any other handler.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define socket context.

```
const socket = io(Configs.serverURL);
const socketContext = React.createContext(null);
export const ContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <socketContext.Provider value={socket}>
      {children}
    </socketContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useSocketContext = () => {
  return useContext(socketContext);
}
```

2. Use this in your root component.

```
<ContextProvider>
  {
  //Your components here
  }
</ContextProvider>
```

3. Access to socket object

```
const socket = useSocketContext();

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('connect', () => { ... });
  ...
}, [dependency1, dependency2])
```

Comment: Good. But what if I need to update the handlers based on some dependency states other than socketRef?

Comment: Updated my answer, Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but the server received a new connection on every re-render and every state update, I need to connect only once, but update the handlers whenever some states update.

Comment: Then you need create Context with React context API

Comment: Any luck? @AhmedHammad

Comment: I didn't try the last update as I came across a different way. I ended up setting a socket constant to the value `io(Configs.serverURL, { autoConnect: false });` and then call its `connect` function inside a `useEffect()`. This way it was available outside the `useEffect()` scope, and also connects only once.

Comment: Don't forget to add ```return() => {socket.off('connect', () => { ... });``` inside ```useEffect()```